# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {#####} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed

Tags: windows, com, registry

we are attempting initialize OneNote in a C# program but have hit a  significant roadblock with permissions issues regarding the COM of the CLSID. We found the appropriate ID, and set the permissions of pretty much every user on the system to have access to pretty much everything possible including Read, Full Control, and Special Permissions.

No matter what though, the error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {#####} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed" still occurs.

We also tried a workaround from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/870655 to alter the Windows subkey to no avail.

At this point we have no ideas left, and would appreciate any advice/assistance offered.

Code:

```
"public OnenoteOcrEngine()
        {
            var app = this.Try(() => new Application(), e => new OcrException("Error initializing OneNote: " + e.Message, e));
            this._page = this.Try(() => new OnenotePage(app), e => new OcrException("Error initializing page.", e));
        }"
```

If it helps any we are following this tutorial here: http://www.journeyofcode.com/free-easy-ocr-c-using-onenote/

Comment: Showing the code that you use to instantiate the COM object and print the error would be very helpful.

Comment: YOu may want to turn on COM tracing per this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926098). If the COM component uses ATL and you can rebuild it with DEBUG turned (`#define DEBUG`) then you can view ATL trace output with Debugview. You can also use the COM+ utility application to change permissions on COM applications.

Comment: Updated the original question with the code for the COM object, the only error we receive though is the one referenced in the title of the question.

Comment: @user2460798 Ok we wrote a debug file following the KB you posted, and we got back an etl file containing incomprehensible text, mainly just the letter Y.

Comment: @user2460798 We were unable to find OneNote in the COM+ services to set permissions so we used Regedit instead. We receive the same error though even after checking all permissions (Read, Full Control, Special Permissions).

Comment: You could try COM tracing per the KB.

Comment: @user2460798 We had performed the COM trace and retrieved a log file however the log file itself only seems to contain errors. We could post the file itself if you think it will help.

Comment: You have to get Microsoft to decode the file for you. Did you get it decoded? If so, then I would say post it.

Comment: @user2460798 Ok how do we go about getting the file decoded by Microsoft though? We were not aware that this was required for the log file.

Comment: The KB article explains the process. Did you read the article?

Comment: @user2460798 Yes we had read the article for contacting Microsoft this specifically: "The binary file must be formatted by Microsoft so that it can be analyzed. Please forward the .etl files to your support contact. For more information about how to contact Microsoft Customer Service and Support, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
295539 How and when to contact Microsoft Customer Service and Support" We were just hoping there was a more automated/self service process, but we will have to go through Microsoft Support it seems.

Comment: @user2460798 Actually we have managed to find the record of the COM request using the Message Analyzer/Network Monitor and we see the SeqNo, EventRecord, and the Payload. What, if anything should we be looking for in there?

Comment: I'm working on a COM+ application. I just got an access denied error (0x80070005). I worked around it by going into Component Services, properties for my COM+ app, the Security tab, and unclicking "Enforce Access Checks for this Application". As to your question, I don't know offhand. Generally I'd be looking for request failures. But I may use Message Analyzer as well. If I do (and have success) I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: @user2460798 Ok, thanks for the info about what you have encountered, we will check to see if what you did in the Security tab for unclicking "Enforce Access Checks for this Application" will correct/workaround our issue as well.

Comment: The other security-ish thing you can do, is to add a role, such as Administrators. Then add users to the role. This explicitly gives those users access to the COM+ application. Doing that I was able to access my COM+ app w/o unclicking "Enforce...".